# How to build two Application in one gradle project

Tags: gradle

I am trying to create a Gradle project that produces two binaries in the distribution folder. Is this possible?

I have two subprojects  and one root gradle.build and when I run `distTar` or `distZip` I does not produce two binaries.
It runs successfully but no zips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible:

*build.gradle.kts*:

```kotlin
subprojects {
    apply<ApplicationPlugin>()
}
```

*subproject1/build.gradle.kts*:

```kotlin
application {
    mainClassName = "com.app.subproject1.Main"
}
```

*subproject2/build.gradle.kts*:

```kotlin
application {
    mainClassName = "com.app.subproject2.Main"
}
```

And that's it. The idea is to apply `application` plugin to both subprojects and then just configure main classes.